# SyntaxError after running eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint

After running eslint my code seems to have stopped working. Here's an example of what happens

Before eslint:

```
foo(a, b, c);
```

After eslint:

```
foo(
   a,
   b,
   c,
);
```

After this transformation, when I try to run my code, I get the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Basically, it seems that the last line -> the ');' seems to bother javascript because it's after a line break? I can't understand why this would cause any trouble.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Trailing comma is not promising

Comment: remove trailing comma `,`

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wuzn5odw/

Comment: Is that really the whole code? Maybe there's something before it that's causing the problem.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#Browser_compatibility